# Rudin's proof of Alaoglu

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Rudin's proofs are usually so slick I wonder why he doesn't just exploit the following fact: (the correction of my error is in the edit)

if $\left \{ \phi_i:X\to \mathbb C \right \}_{i\in I}$ is a family of functions that induces the topology on $X$, then

$\tag1 f: Z\to X\  \text {is continuous} \Leftrightarrow \phi_i \circ f\  \text{is},$

because then we can argue as follows:

give $X^*$ the weak* topology, $\mathbb R^X$ the product topology and define $i:X^*\to \mathbb R^X$ in the obvious way: $i(f)(x)=f(x).$

Then $i$ is a bijection $X^*\to i(X^*),$ and using $(1)$, we see that $i$ and $i^{-1}$ are continuous:

$\pi_x\circ i(f)=f(x)\Rightarrow \pi_x\circ i$ is continuous $\Rightarrow i$ is continuous.

$i^{-1}(f)(x)=$ eval$_x\circ f=f(x)=$ is continuous $\Rightarrow i^{-1}$ is continuous.

In particular, $i(\overline B_{X^{*}}(0,1))$ is closed. (here is my error as pointed out in the answer.) Rudin shows this directly.

Comment: $i$ is an embedding, so for a (weak$^{\ast}$) closed $C \subset X^{\ast}$, we know that $i(C)$ is _relatively closed_ in $i(X^{\ast})$, but what is needed is that $i\bigl(\overline{B}_{X^{\ast}}(0,1)\bigr)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^X$.

Comment: Why? if it is a closed subset of the compact space $\prod _{x\in X}[-\left \| x \right \|,\left \| x \right \|],$ that's enough isn't it?

Comment: What you have proved is that it is a closed subset of $$i(X^{\ast}) \cap \prod_{x\in X} [-\lVert x\rVert, \lVert x\rVert].$$ As it happens, it is also a closed subset of the latter product, but that doesn't just follow from the continuity of $i^{-1}$, since the domain of $i^{-1}$ is only the subspace $i(X^{\ast}) \subset \mathbb{R}^X$, it does not contain $\prod_x [-\lVert x\rVert, \lVert x\rVert]$.

Comment: Yes I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In particular, $i(\overline B_{X^{*}}(0,1))$ is closed.

How do you deduce that? It would follow if $i(X^{\ast})$ is a closed subspace of $\mathbb{R}^X$, but generally it isn't. If $X$ is locally convex, $i(X^{\ast})$ is (in the product topology) dense in the subspace of all linear functionals, continuous or not, and for an infinite-dimensional normed space, there always are discontinuous linear functionals (that requires choice, but Tíkhonov's theorem requires choice too).

So showing that $i\bigl(\overline{B}_{X^{\ast}}(0,1)\bigr)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^X$ does require some work.

Also, Rudin proves the theorem for general topological vector spaces, not only for normed spaces, so one can't generally use $[-\lVert x\rVert,\lVert x\rVert]$.